# Диапазон значений идентификатора

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
$('#close-carousel').click(function (e) {
    jQuery('#carousel1').hide();
});
```

Подскажите, как мне задать диапазон идентификаторов с `#carousel1` до `#carousel30` и вообще возможно ли такое в принципе?

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
$('#close-carousel').click(function (e) {
    for(var i = 1; i<31; ++i)
      jQuery('#carousel'+i).hide();
});
```

А ещё можно все `carousel` положить в один блок и скрыть его.

Answer (score 1):

Лучший способ - это назначить одинаковый CSS класс для всех необходимых элементов. С таким подходом вам не придётся проходить цикл при каждом клике на элементе закрытия вашей карусели:

```
function setReadyToCloseCarouselElements() {
    var lowerLimit = 1,
        upperLimit = 30;
    for (var i = lowerLimit; i <= upperLimit; i++) {
        $("#carousel" + i).addClass("ready-to-close");
    }
}

setReadyToCloseCarouselElements();

$("#close-carousel").click(function (e) {
    $(".ready-to-close").hide();
});
```